# How to Access Dictionary value in html from javascript using '.' operator?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, javascript-objects

I want to access trial.template.Sheet1 array values in html using sheet_name_lists not by writing <%= trial.template.Sheet1 %> directly.I want to complete this task dynamically using array.I am passing array through res.render().

```js
    <!--Javascript file -->
    var trial= {filename: 'ABC.xlsx',
              template: {"Sheet1":["A1","X30","2"]}}
    var sheet_name_lists=["Sheet1"];
    res.render('file.html',{names:sheet_name_lists[0],trials:trial.template});
```

```html
    <!--file.html -->
    <p>file.html</p>
    <p>Want to access trial.template.Sheet1 Value in Html</p>
    <p>Configuration Used Before <%=trials%>.<%=names%> </p><br>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Manipulating_documents

Comment: @Teemu Can you help solve this problem?